# Filter or action hook to assign a template by a field in custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type named 'project' and using a template for it "single-project.php"
which is working fine.

Now I want to have a some differentiation, what I need to assign the template "single-project.php" if a custom value in 'project' post type is mobile and "project-website.php"  template if that custom meta value is equal to website.

means, need code to change the templates dynamically on the basis of custom meta value.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to just call the "project-website.php" file from the "single-project.php" file, if the custom meta value is equal to "website".

Edit your "single-project.php" file:

```
<?php
    $custom_field_value = get_post_meta($post_id,'your-custom-meta-key',true);

    if($custom_field_value == 'website'){
        echo get_template_part('single-project');
    } else {
        *** ENTER YOUR CURRENT CODE FOR SINGLE-PROJECT.PHP HERE ***
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jeremy good point, I already know this but I did it this way , Thanks,

````
function get_custom_post_type_template($single_template)
{
    global $post;
    $object = get_queried_object();
    $id = $object->ID;
    $post_type = $object->post_type;
    $is_mobile = get_field('is_mobile_app', $id);


    if ($is_mobile !== true && $post_type == 'project') {
       return $single_template = dirname(__FILE__) . '/single-project-website.php';
    } else  {
        return $single_template;
    }

//    return $single_template;
}```
````